# Why do I still see some users in the "Mysite" "My Organisation Chart", but I removed them from UPS

Tags: search

I am using sp2010. We have some users which are not working anymore at this company. We are running this procedure:

1) Disable user in AD
2) Lock mysite site collection of the user
3) Go to User Profile Service Application and remove the user

After these procedure I still see the user in the "My Organisation Chart". How can I remove this user also from "My Organisation Chart"? Is this some cache or search indexing?

[image]

Comment: I can see this users in the User Profile Service Application, but in the "Profiles missing from import". Is this the issue? Do I need to remove it also from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I remove these users from "Profiles missing from import" it works fine. These users are not available anymore in the organisation chart.